# Is there a PHP equivalent to <base href>?

Tags: php

Rather than me using ../

`<?php include('../../../header.php'); ?>`

Is there a better way? Such as using `<base href>` for HTML

Comment: Use absolute paths. You can define a constant which links to the root of your application which means you can work from there.

Comment: ini_set to change your include_path

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Thanks for the quick answer. Can I have an example? If my header.php is in my root would it be `<?php include('/header.php'); ?>`? Or should I use a URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it by using `<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/header.php"); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

include($root.'/projectname/filename.php');
```

Comment: if my header.php is in my root, would it be: `$root = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]

 include("$root/header.php");`

Comment: root of your project??

Comment: `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] ` will give path till your `htdocs`.

Answer (score 0):

I use this construction:

```
define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(__DIR__));

#all includes use the constant ROOT_PATH:
require_once ROOT_PATH.'/controllers/controllers.php';
```